# Make ending curly brace of block go down an extra newline in Golang

Tags: indentation, golang

Upon pressing enter inside a newly created block I would like the Emacs to move the ending curly brace an extra newline down, and then indent the cursor. Is this possible?

*Example*

Before pressing Enter

```
for i := range x {<cursor>}
```

After pressing Enter once I get this

```
for i := range x {
<cursor>}
```

However what I would like to get is this

```
for i := range x {
    <cursor>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) for exactly this. It uses sort of a cryptic syntax in
the `:post-handlers` keyword for doing things after you insert a pair and press
a button. Here's a pair config to do what you want:

```el
(sp-pair "{" nil :post-handlers '(("||\n[i]" "RET")))
```

And the relevant documentation on the Github wiki: [Pre and Post Action Hooks](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Permissions#pre-and-post-action-hooks)

Comment: This was _exactly_ what I was looking for :)

I actually already use smartparens (which is the whole reason my cursor ends up in between the curly braces) but must admit I didn't quite get the action hooks.